# Error: XML content doesn't seem XML

Tags: r

I have an .XML file in the same working directory with all the other files and I have correctly set the working directly where I want it to be.

When I try and run the R code, it returns the following error:

> Error: XML content doesn't seem XML

I did go through other topics on here for similar issue, but they were all related to a URL. But I have an .XML file in the working directory. I know the file works perfectly fine, because it worked smoothly for my colleague. But it is returning this error for me.

I run this code on a terminal server and the file is located in a local shared drive.

Can someone provide any insight as to what might be causing it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you post the (relevant) R code and the output of `readChar(file("<your_xml_file>"), 80)`? In general, please read the info about [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you.

Comment: AFAIK, you can either read an XML which is on the same system where you run your R code, or in a publicly accessible location (a URL, if you will).

Try getting your file to the server where you're running the code, or use some tunnelling software (like ngrok) to make your XML file publicly accessible, and then use it as a URL.